# Can PhpStorm code comments link to command line?

Tags: ide, phpstorm

Most IDEs allow for and detect links in the comments, so that you can just click them to get to bring up the page.  You can also click functions to change files, etc.  Does anyone know if there is a way to format a comment, so that it can be clicked to enter a command line instruction?

For example: if I put this in a php file for PhpStorm, then I'd be able to mouse over the url, hold down the command button, and click the link to pop open a browser.

```
/**
 * Class Helpers
 * @package App\Core
 *          
 * @link http://www.billy.com 
 */
```

Is it possible to get that type of thing to work for a command line entry?  Is there a PhpStorm plugin or anything?

Comment: ?? Please explain with some example or mockups.

Comment: I understand the `@link` -- not a problem. What I mean is -- what exactly do you mean by *"to work for a command line entry"*? Do you mean something like having `php artisan clear:cache` or some other command ... that you can click and it will be executed in terminal?

Comment: ya - that's exactly the type of thing I would find usefull

Comment: I see. Unfortunately I'm not aware of such plugin. I may only suggest use External Tools functionality .. or execute them via some task runner (e.g. Gulp/Grunt) or something like that (maybe BashSupport where you may create custom Run/Debug Configurations...)